# check if unknown interface{} is empty

Tags: go, reflection

Hello I would like to know how I would be able to validate in Go if an `interface{}` is empty.
I tried `reflect.TypeOf(v) == nil`, but it always returns `false`.

```
    var h  Bar
    var t  Foo
    pointers := make([]interface{}, 0)
    pointers = append(pointers, &h)
    pointers = append(pointers, &t)

func test(byteValue []byte, data []interface{}) {
    for _, v := range  data {
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(v) == nil)
        if err := lib.Unmarshal(byteValue, v); err == nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? You can compare an interface directly with `nil`, or do you want to determine if it contains a type that is empty, like a slice or map?

Comment: basically i pass a structs pointer and i need to check if it is empty without any modified fields.

Comment: @AegisDev that's not empty. There is no such thing as a field being empty. All types in Go have a [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value).

Comment: yes with zeros.

Comment: I would need to know if the a struct I run through in the for is empty with zeros

Comment: Do you have control over types `Foo` and `Bar`? Are those the only concrete types that your slice of `interface{}` is going to contain? If so, you don't need reflection; you can simply use a type switch. See https://play.golang.org/p/KR467c3E9uY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
func isZero(v interface{}) bool {
    // reflect.ValueOf will panic on a nil value.
    if v == nil {
        return true
    }
    return reflect.ValueOf(v).IsZero()
}
```

[Example](https://play.golang.org/p/5IBkNLPSvv6)

Comment: i tried something like this, but i was not successful because i am passing a pointer of a var